# Failure of Luroth's theorem for transcendence degree 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Can somebody give an example which shows the failure of Luroth's theorem for transcendence degree 3 over $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: From the geometric point of view, you are asking for a variety of dimension 3 that is unirational but not rational. The famous examples are smooth cubic and quartic hypersurfaces in $\mathbf P^4$. Is this the kind of answer you are looking for?

Comment: @Asal I would prefer a algebraic explanation, but perhaps that is not that easy.

Comment: Dear user114539, that's a good question. I don't know of a purely algebraic explanation, and in fact I would be surprised to learn that one exists. But I am not an expert; perhaps @GeorgesElencwajg might have something to say about this.

Comment: Agree with @AsalBeagDubh. I doubt there is an algebraic proof of Lüroth in dimension $2$ (in characteristic $0$).

Comment: Dear @Asal: I have exactly the same feeling as you but I certainly can't say anything more precise than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In geometric terms:

A complex variety $V$ of dimension $n$ is rational if there exists a birational map $\mathbb P^n  --\to V $ or, equivalently, if its function field is purely transcendental i.e. there exists a field isomorphism $Rat (V)\cong \mathbb C(t_1,\cdots, t_n)$ .
More generally $V$ is called unirational if there exists a rational surjective map $\mathbb P^N  --\to V $ or, equivalently, if its function field is a subfield of a purely transcendental field i.e. there exists a field embedding $Rat (V) \subset  \mathbb C(t_1,\cdots, t_N)$ .

The Lüroth problem  will thus be solved negatively if one can prove that there exists a unirational variety which is not rational.
For dimension $\geq 3$ the existence of such a variety was  proved in 1971 by three teams of mathematicians, using different ideas : Artin-Mumford, Clemens-Griffiths and Iskovskikh-Manin.

In conclusion, it is not true  that an extension field $\mathbb C\subset K$ of transcendence degree three over $\mathbb C$ which is a subfield $K\subset \mathbb C(t_1,\cdots,t_N)$ of a purely transcendental extension  must necessarily be isomorphic to a purely transcendental extension $\mathbb C(u_1,u_2,u_3)$.
[For transcendence degrees one or two  however it is true]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation above, but are you aware of any purely algebraic explanation?

Comment: Dear user114539, I don't know about a purely algebraic explanation and I would not be surprised if none existed. But let me emphasize that I don't know for sure.